# Illegal name for migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to generate a new user model, and I could have sworn that this worked before

```
$ rails generate migration User.rb
```

but now it complains that this is illegal.  I keep getting an error:

Illegal name for migration file: user.rb
    (only lower case letters, numbers, and '_' allowed)

As you can see user.rb is only lowercase.

Comment: It should be `rails generate migration User`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, issue here is with `.` which you have between `User` and `rb`, i.e.: `User.rb`. If you change it to: `rails generate migration Userrb` then it should work.

However, you can be more efficient while generating a migration by following a small convention:

- To create users table:

  > $ rails generate migration create_users

  or:

  > $ rails generate migration CreateUsers
- To have some columns while creating users table:

  > $ rails generate migration create_users name:string email:string address:text

  or:

  > $ rails generate migration CreateUsers name:string email:string address:text

**UPDATE**: Apologies for not consider your line: *generate a new user model*. If you want to generate a model then you can run these convenient commands:

- To create User model which will also create users table migration by default:

  > $ rails generate model user

  or:

  > $ rails generate model User
- To create User model which will also create users table migration with some attributes by default:

  > $ rails generate model user name:string email:string address:text

  or:

  > $ rails generate model User name:string email:string address:text

Answer (score 0):

Change to *user* instead of *User.rb*.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations should be like this.

```
rails generate migration add_email_to_users email:string
```

I don't know what are trying to achieve by User.rb. Although refer [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) doc. Its a good start if you are not aware of how migrations work.